# Cannot connect to sql server from vpn client

Tags: vpn, sql

I have a client that using openvpn is connecting to a remote lan where i have a openvpn server (zeroshell)
i can use any service without troubles.
Now i am trying to connect to a sql server sitting on anoher subnet.

My client --> openvpn server --> router --> sql server

Openvpn server is on lan 192.168.50.x
The router connects lan 192.168.50.x to 192.168.60.x

SQL server is on 192.168.60.x
My client pings without problems the sql server after being connected to the vpn but i can't set odbc to connect to it.

What is wrong?
what should I set?

Ps
Client is xp,  SQL server is windows 2003, vpn server is linux (zeroshell)

Comment: What happens when you try to telnet to port 1433?

Comment: I should do telnet sqlserverip 1433, right?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue to me.

Comment: Can you access any other service on that remote VPN host other than pinging it?

Comment: If you're using the standard sql server port then yes you should be able to telnet to it.  Routing may not be set up properly on the sql server if it needs to traverse subnets.  Can you ping your internal OpenVPN IP from the sql server?

Comment: @Tim yes, my friend... I can access web servers, vnc servers and openssh servers without problems on different computers.

Comment: @orbitron I have to check that and I'll let you know: thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the xp client I've been trying to use had problems.

A fresh install solved everything: Sql server works great with openvpn.